# How to display a list in django template?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

A list is created. I want to display the list in the template.

```
search_query=[]
#...
#code here
#...

return render(request, 'query/list.html', {'search_query'})
```

But it is giving this error - **"context must be a dict rather than set."**

In the list.html

```
{% for c in suggest_search_query%}
    <p>{{c}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is in the call to `render(..)`:

```
return render(request, 'query/list.html', {'search_query'})
#                                         ^     set      ^
```

You here did *not* construct a dictionary, but a **`set`** (the notation is a bit similar). A set is a collection of unique hashable values. But you do *not* map keys to values in a set, that is what a dictionary does.

You need to convert it to:

```
return render(request, 'query/list.html', {'suggest_search_query': search_query})
```

to define a dictionary that maps `suggest_search_query` to the `search_query` variable.